# In Kubernetes, how to make sure one pod only serve one connection

Tags: kubernetes

*Situation*

I want to have a `pool` of `serving` pods (say I have 50 `serving` pods lying around). They will be exposed via a LoadBalancer Service.

I want to make sure that:

1. each pod serves only one TCP connection and keep this connection alive until the client terminates it. Until the end of this pod's life, it will not receive any other TCP connections.
2. Once the client terminates the connection, the pod cleans up and destroys it self.
3. Another pod is spinned up to match the desired replica number. Since it's not currently serving any TCP connection, it can be chosen to serve the next TCP connection that goes into the LoadBalancer service.

*Example*

```
1. Initially, a `Deployment` specifies a pool of 2 pods behind a LoadBalancer Service.

[1] [2]


------LoadBalancer-------



2. A client initiates a TCP connection to the LoadBalancer (e.g. telnet loadbalancer.domain.com 80) and the TCP connection is routed to the first vacant pod.

[1] [2]
 |
 |
------LoadBalancer-------
 |
 |
cl1



3. 24 hours after that (assuming data has been passing between client1 & pod1), another client hits to the same Load Balancer public domain. Since pod1 is serving client1, I want the second client to be routed to another vacant pod, such as pod 2.

[1] [2]
 |   |
 |   |
------LoadBalancer-------
 |   |
 |   |
cl1 cl2



4. 24 hours after that, client 1 terminates the connection, I want pod1 to do clean up and destroy itself shortly afterwards. No new connections should be routed to it. That leaves pod2 the only one still running.

[2]
 |
 |
------LoadBalancer-------
 |
 |
cl2



5. `Deployment` will create additional pods to ensure the number of replicas. So pod3 is created.

[1] [3]
 |   
 |   
------LoadBalancer-------
 |   
 |   
cl1 



6. Another client hits the same endpoint and is routed to a vacant pod (pod 3 in this case).

[1] [3]
 |   |
 |   |
------LoadBalancer-------
 |   |
 |   |
cl1 cl3

And so on and so forth.
```

Anybody has any ideas how this can be solved on K8s?

Answer (score 1):

So I guess this would work.

First set a ReadinessProbe to poll an endpoint/tcp port on your pod very agressivly (as often as possible).

Then as soon as you get a connection make sure that the ReadinessProbe fails, but at the same time make sure the LivenessProbe DOESN'T fail.

Finally, after the client disconnects terminate the application.

Your deplopment needs to have enough replicas to serve all clients that can enter simultanious since one pod will never serve two clients.

Comment: You know what, this is a very creative way of using the probes. I'm gonna try them out.

Comment: I just tested it but it doesn't work. When you fail the readiness probe, the connection is also forced cut.

Comment: Oh, so I guess when the ip is removed from the virtual ip in iptables it also kills the connection :(
Well, it was a good attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at k8s' `sessionAffinity`, it might help I think. [This link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace) says:

> kube-proxy takes the `SessionAffinity` setting of the Service into account when deciding which backend Pod to use.

and

> If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity based on the client’s IP addresses by setting `service.spec.sessionAffinity` to “ClientIP” (the default is “None”). You can also set the maximum session sticky time by setting `service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds` appropriately.

After the client terminates, make the server return a failure code at a path like `/clientstatus`, use [readinessProbe/livenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) to check this path every second, and delete the pod if readinessProbe/livenessProbe fails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I knew about `sessionAffinity`. It won't solve my problem. However, the idea about killing the pod after the client terminates makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to achieve this with a serverless technology on top of kubernetes. Check [Knative serving](https://github.com/knative/serving) which is a serverless technology. But in this case there is no pool of pods pre created, pods are created on demand when client request comes and gets destroyed after the request finishes.

Comment: thank you for telling me about Knative. I didn't know it exists. Why do you think this is only possible with a serverless technology on top of kubernetes?

Comment: I wanted mean kubernetes probably does not have this feature in a straightforward way..unless you do some mucking around the core abstractions provided by kubernetes as mentioned by @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy the `pods` with [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) so you could use [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services).

> A Headless Service does not contain a ClusterIP. Instead, it creates several Endpoints that are used to produce DNS records. Each DNS record is bound to a pod. All of this is done internally by Kubernetes, but it’s good to have an idea about how it does it.

You can read more about [Kubernetes StatefulSets 101 - State of the Pods](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-statefulsets-101-state-of-the-pods).

You then can implement a script (deployed in front of the StatefulSet) that will route client to one DNS record.

You could also have a look for some message queues brokers.

There are [KubeMQ](https://kubemq.io/), [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [Redis](https://redis.io/). There is also Pub/Sub on [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same task and I didn't find kubernetes built-in solutions. All of them are outside of it. The key problem is that there is no such built-in metric as connections count that could be used for autoscaling. And this is ridiculous as the service knows how many connections it have established to the pods. So the HPA should ask the service for this number and if it is more then configured limit (could be at least zero) then spin up new pod.